# Error during sass installation for Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, rubygems

I am trying to install sass after installing ruby, but I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\HEDi-PC>gem install sass
ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
    unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first things first: use virtual machine with Ubuntu in it, otherwise you will have many more wierd errors with various packages. Ruby and Rails have some quick-start procedures for Windows users, but after I used Windows with Rails for about a year, I found that it's best to stop doing that.

This particular error should go after you change encoding in your terminal:

```
chcp 1252
```

This happens because Ruby doesn't know how to handle `CP720` terminal encoding.

Comment: thanks @EugZol . solved